# Check if object exists or not with uLkJSON

Tags: delphi

```
try
    FStrJSONResponse:= IdHTTP1.Get('http://192.168.1.21/api/users');
    js:= TlkJSON.ParseText(FStrJSONResponse) as TlkJSONobject;
    if js.Field['error'].Value = true then
    begin
      FStrErrorMsg:= js.Field['message'].Value;
      Exit;
    end;

    SetLength(Result, js.Field['data'].Count);
    for i := 0 to js.Field['data'].Count-1 do
    begin
      if VarIsStr(js.Field['data'].Child[i].Field['id'].Value) then
        Result[i].identifier:= js.Field['data'].Child[i].Field['id'].Value;
      if VarIsStr(js.Field['data'].Child[i].Field['email'].Value) then
        Result[i].email:= js.Field['data'].Child[i].Field['email'].Value;

  finally
    js.Free;
  end;
```

Hello

I am using uLkJSON. API does not return error object if error is not occured. So when the error not occured, delphi throw an exception access not violation. How can i check `js` has `error` or not ?

Comment: You need to check that the `js.Field['error']` is Assigned before accessing its value

Comment: thanks kobik  .  .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simple function for check object in pascal

```
if Assigned(TheObject)  then

or 

if TheObject<>nil then
```

edit your code with

```
if Assigned(js.Field['error']) then
```

or

```
if js.Field['error']<>nil then
```

assume for checking pointer or value error is exist

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/350567) by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.